# Как передать slug в urls.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, slug

Уважаемые профи. Пытаюсь передать slug в urls.py. Чтобы отображалась страница с категориями по адресу: http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/obo-vsem/. Но выдает ошибку (что не так) Как исправить?:

```
TypeError at /category/obo-vsem/

get_category_article() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'
```

Views.py

```
def get_category_article(request, category_id):
    category=get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    posts=Posts.objects.order_by('-pub_date').filter(is_active=True, category=category)
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'posts': posts})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', get_category_article, name="get_category_article"),
```

Answer (score 1):

Не особо помню как с именованными аргументами работать, но попробуйте так:

```
def get_category_article(request, slug):
```

То есть по идее, имя аргумента аналогичное имени указанному в регулярном выражении в url, должно присутствовать во вьюхе.

Comment: При его добавлении выскакивает другая ошибка:                                `def get_category_article(request, category_id, slug):
    category=get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    posts=Posts.objects.order_by('-pub_date').filter(is_active=True, category=category)
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'posts': posts})`                                                                                           Ошибка: `TypeError at /category/obo-vsem/

get_category_article() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_id'`

Comment: Это естественно, потому, что category_id, тоже нужно переименовать.

Comment: Я понятия не имею как у вас там устроен код. Я ответил про именованный аргумент. Думаю, что если у вас вызывают проблемы работа даже с обычными идентификаторами, то в это дело соваться не стоит.